# Reeder (RSS App from App Store) uses 60 GB of disk space. How do I clean this up?

Tags: applications, disk-space, macos, rss, google

```
> pwd
/Users/seline/Library/Containers/com.reederapp.rkit2.mac/Data/Library/Application Support/Reeder/rkit
> du -sh * | gsort -h
8.0K    rkit-edit.db
 28K    rkit-edit.db-wal
 32K    rkit-data.db-shm
 32K    rkit-edit.db-shm
 32K    rkit.db-shm
1000K   icons
 55M    rkit.db
 69M    rkit-data.db
 19G    rkit-data.db-wal
 37G    rkit.db-wal

> du -sh .
 58G    .
> pwd
/Users/seline/Library/Containers/com.reederapp.rkit2.mac/Data
```

I subscribe to about 200 feeds, lots of Imgur feeds with pictures and videos.

Is this behavior normal? How do I clean this up?

Comment: Do you want to keep your history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reeder's cache can get cleared in its preferences:

[image]

Unlike the iOS version you can't limit the number of articles in the cache though.